# How do I parse (potentially unknown) key/value pairs from a list of strings with default values?

Tags: python

I have a string column in a Pandas DataFrame that contains database settings and I want to turn the key/value pairs into new columns in the DataFrame, filling in any missing values with `True`.

Here's what one of the strings looks like:

```
Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=SIMPLE, Version=706, Collation=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, SQLSortOrder=52, IsAutoCreateStatistics, IsAutoUpdateStatistics, IsFullTextEnabled
```

And I'd like the output to look something like:

```
| Status | Updateability | UserAccess | Recovery | Version | Collation                    | SQLSortOrder | IsAutoCreateStatistics | IsAutoUpdateStatistics | IsFullTextEnabled |
| ONLINE | READ_WRITE    | MULTI_USER | SIMPLE   | 706     | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS | 52           | True                   | True                   | True              |
```

I've tried iterating through the rows, parsing the string with the `re.sub` and `split()`, which got me to the key/value pairs for settings which follow the `key=value` format. I hard-coded the known boolean keys (as shown in the code below), but I'd like to have this work on unknown booleans.

The point I'm getting stuck on now is rolling the results for a particular key/value pair back up to the correct column/row it's supposed to go in.

```
import re

_status = ['Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=SIMPLE, Version=706, Collation=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, SQLSortOrder=52, IsAutoCreateStatistics, IsAutoUpdateStatistics, IsFullTextEnabled', 'Status=OFFLINE, Updateability=READ, UserAccess=SINGLE_USER, Recovery=SIMPLE, Version=706, Collation=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, SQLSortOrder=53, IsAutoCreateStatistics, IsAutoUpdateStatistics, IsTornPageDetectionEnabled']

_status = [re.sub('IsAutoCreateStatistics', 'IsAutoCreateStatistics=True', _s) for _s in _status]
_status = [re.sub('IsAutoUpdateStatistics', 'IsAutoUpdateStatistics=True', _s) for _s in _status]
_status = [re.sub('IsFullTextEnabled', 'IsFullTextEnabled=True', _s) for _s in _status]
_status = [re.sub('IsTornPageDetectionEnabled', 'IsTornPageDetectionEnabled=True', _s) for _s in _status]

_rows = []

for _row in _status:
    _kvs = []
    for _kv in _row.split(','):
        _key, _val = _kv.split('=')
        _d = {_key.strip(): _val.strip()}
        _kvs.append(_d)
    _rows.append(_kvs)

_rows
```

Which nets me:

```
[[{'Status': 'ONLINE'},
  {'Updateability': 'READ_WRITE'},
  {'UserAccess': 'MULTI_USER'},
  {'Recovery': 'SIMPLE'},
  {'Version': '706'},
  {'Collation': 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'},
  {'SQLSortOrder': '52'},
  {'IsAutoCreateStatistics': 'True'},
  {'IsAutoUpdateStatistics': 'True'},
  {'IsFullTextEnabled': 'True'}],
 [{'Status': 'OFFLINE'},
  {'Updateability': 'READ'},
  {'UserAccess': 'SINGLE_USER'},
  {'Recovery': 'SIMPLE'},
  {'Version': '706'},
  {'Collation': 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'},
  {'SQLSortOrder': '53'},
  {'IsAutoCreateStatistics': 'True'},
  {'IsAutoUpdateStatistics': 'True'},
  {'IsTornPageDetectionEnabled': 'True'}]]
```

This is the best I've come up with so far, and it looks like I'm close, but I'm sure there's a *much* more Pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simplify  using *str.partition*,no need for any regex, just split the string :

```
s = "Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=SIMPLE, Version=706, Collation=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, SQLSortOrder=52, IsAutoCreateStatistics, IsAutoUpdateStatistics, IsFullTextEnabled"

def repl(s):
    for sub in s.split(", "):
        k, _, v = sub.partition("=")
        yield (k, v) if v else (k, "True")
```

Any substring after splitting when partitioned on `=` that has an empty string for *v* means we don't have a pairing so we need no nor care about any prior knowledge of potential keys:

```
In [9]: s = "Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=SIMPLE, Version=706, Collation=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, SQLSortOrder=52, IsAutoCreateStatistics, IsAutoUpdateStatistics, IsFullTextEnabled"

In [10]: dict(repl(s))
Out[10]: 
{'Collation': 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',
 'IsAutoCreateStatistics': 'True',
 'IsAutoUpdateStatistics': 'True',
 'IsFullTextEnabled': 'True',
 'Recovery': 'SIMPLE',
 'SQLSortOrder': '52',
 'Status': 'ONLINE',
 'Updateability': 'READ_WRITE',
 'UserAccess': 'MULTI_USER',
 'Version': '706'}
```

Also if the spaces are possibly not there you could just split on `","` and strip the whitespace or use the *csv* lib settin `skipinitialspace=True` which will handle `"foo, bar"` and `"foo,bar"`:

```
from csv import reader
from itertools import chain

def repl(s):
    for sub in chain(*reader([s], skipinitialspace=True)):
        k, _, v = sub.partition("=")
        yield (k, v) if v else (k, "True")


print(dict(repl(s)))
```

if you just wanted to create a new df and all keys are the same:

```
from csv import reader
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

def repl(s):
    d = {}
    for sub in chain(*reader([s], skipinitialspace=True)):
        k, _, v = sub.partition("=")
        d[k] = v if v else "True"
    return d




df =  pd.DataFrame.from_records(map(repl ,status))

print(df)
```

But as per the discussion, if you see a key later that you habe not seen in the first dict, you will get nan for the row value not  `True`

Comment: Your `sub.partition('=')` suggestion fixed the unknown keys problem. I added `strip()` to remove the leading space (which will likely be there, but I wouldn't count on it). Now I just need to get that result back into a DataFrame so I can join it back to the original table.

Comment: @zhespelt, so you want two rows from one? Can you add a sample of a df as it and what you want it to look like after?

Comment: I want to transform the list of lists of parameters (of which the `_status` variable represents the first 2 records) into columns in the original DataFrame.

Comment: @zhespelt, are the keys always repeating?

Comment: So for each string in `_status`, the keys become the column headers (if they don't already exist) and the values become the records. Once the values or `True` are inserted, I can fill the empty boolean values with `False` and drop the original `status` column from the DataFrame.

Comment: Most of the keys are repeating, but some records may have new keys or be missing keys (or values in the case of the boolean ones).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116524/discussion-between-zhespelt-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1):

Building up on Padraic Cunninghams Answer I came up with this solution. Depending on the formatting constraints of the input, this solution with a regex can be more or less robust than the split/strip solution.

```
import pandas
import re

def repl(s):
    for sub in re.findall('[\w=]+', s):
        k, _, v = sub.partition("=")
        if v:
            yield k,v
        else:
            yield k, "True"

_status = [ 'Status=ONLINE1, IsFullTextEnabled', 
            'Status=ONLINE2, IsFullTextEnabled']

data = []
for _row in _status:
    data.append(dict(repl(_row)))

print(pandas.DataFrame(data))
```

Answer (score -2):

If you know that is how the string will be, you can do the following:

```
your_string = 'Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, ThisValueWillBeTrue'
your_list = your_string.split(sep=', ')
your_dict = {i.split(sep='=')[0] : i.split(sep='=')[1] if len(i.split(sep='=')) > 1 else True for i in your_list}
```